# only hard refresh works first time after building container with react docker and nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, service, worker

I have a react and Nginx container.
The react site works normally fine. but when I update the latest code and rebuild the container and restart it. I have to do hard refresh the page first time to get the homepage normal refresh wont work . once the hard refresh the page the next refresh will work normally .

I will get the following error when I do a normal refresh after building the container.

''' Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'main.5a72dfd2.js:1 '''

below is my nginx config

'''
server {

```
    server_name sample.exapmle.com;

    access_log /var/log/folder/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/folder/error.log;

    location / {
             proxy_pass http://app:4000/;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;
        }

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on http2;
listen 443 ssl http2;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/ssl.key;
```

}

'''

Comment: Please add some `code` to your question.

Comment: What browser are you on ? Are you sure your browser isn't caching the page ?

Comment: i am  checking on chrome and firefox .

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni have a look at my config i am saying not to store , but still not sure about that . but when i check cache